# Regex to select matches in ascending order

Tags: regex

Is it possible to create a regex that will return the matches in a sorted order?

For example with the string

```
'banana apple'
```

Is there a regex similar to `/([a-z]+)/` that can return the matches in an alphanumeric sorted order.

```
matches => {'apple', 'banana'}
```

Note:
I'm not sure it's possible, however regexp is pretty much the only tool available to solve this issue within an existing application.

In this particular scenario, the number of matches is known in advance, but not the order in which they will come.

Comment: Regex matching isn't really intended for this task. You could conceivably generate a complex regex that would give you the desired result, but whatever language you are using the regex from, will have better, faster and easier ways to sort the matches once you have them.

Comment: @Grismar nope, there is no regex that can sort words lexicographically, and it's not difficult to prove it.

Comment: @alfasin, I agree with what you're saying in principle, but of course someone could generate a regex of arbitrary length that would simply list out the matches in alphabetical order, by first characters, or by a set number of characters - but to cover any and all words, that would effectively amount to a regex containing the entire dictionary. I suppose the difference of opinion would be "impossible" vs. "stupendously impractical and silly".

Comment: @Grismar agreed. in order to do that you'll need to know in advance what the input is. only then it's possible.

Comment: In this scenario, the regex is passed as configuration to a large 3rd party library. So using common language functions is what I'm trying to avoid.  A complex regular expression could have been preferable to modifying and maintaining the code.

Comment: @alfasin it's really not worth debating, since we already agree - but yes, I agree, or you'd need to not care about the sorting beyond a certain index in the text.

Comment: you're basically going to have to take @alfasin's advice, unless your problem is more specific than just "sort alphanumerically" for unknown input, because then they are 100% correct.

Comment: add to that: it's easier to maintain a simple regex and do the sorting in the code, which is a good enough of a reason to not do it in the regex even if it was possible.

Comment: agreed - if using the third party library is better with sorting than without, it probably has a built-in feature for it, *or* you're better off with another library, *or* you should sort the input before passing it to the third party library, in which case the regex will only have to match the words, which happen to be sorted.

Comment: @SteveE. can you provide a code example of the third party library usage that shows how and why you'd want to pass the data and the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Collect all the matches and sort them afterwards.

Comment: That's what I thought, would be very happy to be proved wrong on this occasion.

Comment: As discussed above, such a sorting is possible only for a known-in-advance fixed input.